# Primefaces photocam - Issue in capturing image in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, webcam.js

I am using Primefaces (V6.2) photocam component in my jsf application to capture images to process in tessaract api.

I used the sample code as in https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/photoCam.xhtml.
So far code works fine in laptop and android smartphones (chrome + Firefox ) and I am able to capture the image in desired resolution.

Issue : 
 when I open the application in IOS devices in safari browser I am able to access the camera and capture the image, but the image stored in system is either plain black or plain white. Size of the image varies from 2KB to 60KB based on the image resolution.

I used the latest webcam.js from github https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs  to avoid the known webcam loading issue in primefaces 6.2 version which runs on older version of webcam.js.

xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<f:view locale="#{bean.locale}">
    <h:head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <h:outputScript library="#{application.resourceid}" name="js/webcam.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function setparams(){
    var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
    // device detection
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
        isMobile = true;
    }
    Webcam.set({
        // live preview size
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        // Final output size of captured image
        dest_width: 1280, 
        dest_height: 720, 
        // final cropped size
        crop_width: 1280,
        crop_height: 720,

    });
    if(isMobile){
        Webcam.set({
            constraints: {
                facingMode: { exact: 'environment' } // to force chrome to load the Rear camera instead of default front camera
                }   
        });     
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setparams();
});
</script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body id="body">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                <p:photoCam widgetVar="pc" listener="#{document.oncapture}"
                    update="photo" />
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Capture" onclick="PF('pc').capture()" />
                <p:outputPanel id="photo">
                    <p:graphicImage name="#{document.imgsrc}"  rendered="#{not empty document.imgsrc}" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

method

```
@ManagedBean(name = "document")
@ViewScoped
public class PhotoCamView {

    private String filename;
    private String imgsrc;

    public String getImgsrc() {
        return imgsrc;
    }

    public void setImgsrc(String imgsrc) {
        this.imgsrc = imgsrc;
    }

    private String getRandomImageName() {
        int i = (int) (Math.random() * 10000000);

        return String.valueOf(i);
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

   public void oncapture(CaptureEvent captureEvent) {
        filename = getRandomImageName();
        byte[] data = captureEvent.getData();
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        String newFileName = externalContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "demo" +
                File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "photocam" + File.separator + filename + ".jpeg";
        // This path is used to render the captured image in page
        imgsrc =  "demo" +  File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "photocam" + File.separator + filename + ".jpeg"; 
        FileImageOutputStream imageOutput;
        try {
            imageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(newFileName));
            imageOutput.write(data, 0, data.length);
            imageOutput.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            LOGGER.trace("Error in writing captured image.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Been trying to identify what went wrong in the code. I tried to loading the IOS device by removing the setparams() javascript method too. But nothing worked out.

Comment: Have you tried PF 7.0RC1?  I have fixed these two PhotoCam issues since 6.2 and 
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4094  and https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3755

Comment: Also that is really strange.  The only issues I see about safari on webcam.js page https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/pull/283 and this guy complaining about blue tint https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/79

Comment: Ahh sorry look at this one: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/203  Same issue you are having.

Comment: @Melloware Thanks for your valuable inputs , will check those items.